# Integrate PaintcodeApp swift code into Xcode

Tags: swift, paintcode

I have an svg image from the designer. I want to get equivalent swift code from Paintcode app so that it fits perfectly inside a circular button . How do i set the frame?
Suppose i have two circular buttons as shown in below screenshot and i wanna add a new image to the empty circular button.

[image]

Below is the image i want to add into the empty circular button so that it fits proportionally inside the circle. Please help me to get swift code from Paintcodeapp.

[image]

Comment: A button background image doesn't have a "frame". It's an image, not a view.

Comment: @matt i agree but should i include the canvas inside a frame so that image dimensions are not constant instead relative to frame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use PaintCode Mac App to convert SVG to Swift CoreGraphics drawing code.
It is very simple 
Just import svg file to paint code, it will automatically generate swift code.

Refer screen shots
[image]
[image]

Comment: thanks! i have updated my question.Could you please look into it,